# How to arrange an array with objects based on another array?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have this unsorted array (containing objects)

```
   toSortArray = [{taskID: 1, "title": "something1", subtasks: {}},
                  {taskID: 5, "title": "something5", subtasks: {}},
                  {taskID: 8, "title": "something8", subtasks: {}}];
```

and I have this array that is dynamically populated based on the correct positioning of the taskIDs

```
sortingArray = [8, 1, 5];
```

What I am trying to do is to sort 'toSortArray' with the exact same order as stated in 'sortingArray'.

I have found a somewhat called solution here stating this:

```
var arr = ['one','four','two'];
var test = [{
    key: 'one'
},{
  key: 'two'
},{
  key: 'four'
}];

function sortFunction(a,b){
    var indexA = arr.indexOf(a['key']);
    var indexB = arr.indexOf(b['key']);
    if(indexA < indexB) {
        return -1;
    }else if(indexA > indexB) {
        return 1;
    }else{
        return 0;        
    }
}
```

However, it doesn't work for me. I replaced the placeholders for:

```
function sortFunction (a,b) {
        var indexA = sortingArray.indexOf(a["taskID"]);
        console.log(indexA);
        var indexB = sortingArray.indexOf(b["taskID"]);
        console.log(indexB);
        if (indexA < indexB) {
            return -1;
        } else if (indexA > indexB) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

When I debugged (as you can see I am console logging the indexA and indexB). They always return -1, which means no such index is found.

My question is how to get to compare "taskID" value and the sortingArray elements.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer: In the examples, I've remove properties not relevant to the question, and also renamed `taskID` to `tID` for brevity.

You can use `Array.prototype.reduce` to achieve the desired result:

```js
let arr = [{tID: 1},{tID: 5},{tID: 8}];
let sArr = [8, 1, 5];

const result = sArr.reduce((a,v) => a.concat(arr.find(({tID})=>tID===v)), []);

console.log(result);
```

You can also use `Array.prototype.sort`:

```js
let arr = [{tID: 1},{tID: 5},{tID: 8}];
let sArr = [8, 1, 5];

const result = arr.sort(
  ({tID: aID}, {tID: bID}) => sArr.indexOf(aID) - sArr.indexOf(bID));

console.log(result);
```

`Array.prototype.map` will also do the job:

```js
let arr = [{tID: 1},{tID: 5},{tID: 8}];
let sArr = [8, 1, 5];

const result = sArr.map(i => arr.find(({tID}) => tID === i));

console.log(result);
```

`map` and `reduce` will probably perform faster than `sort` because each iteration only requires a single lookup (`find`) in the `toSortArray`, as opposed to `sort`, which requires two lookups (`indexOf`).

Comment: Personally I'd go with the `sort` option, it's more obvious what is happening for eyeball parsing.

Comment: @JonP Actually I find the `map` variant easiest to grab.

Comment: `sort` makes it obvious we're sorting, but I'll concede `map` is maybe a little more obvious on the sort logic.

Comment: @connexo, thanks for your input. I’ve marked your comment as a solution based on the fact you intervened first, while the comments of the others also worked. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the `toSortArray` based upon each of the `sortingArray` element values. Using `filter` will return an array of one element that matches the current value. Since filter returns an array, use `flatMap()` to iterate over the `sortingArray` and return a single, sorted array in the order of the `sortingArray`.

```js
const toSortArray = [{taskID: 1, "title": "something1", subtasks: {}},
                  {taskID: 5, "title": "something5", subtasks: {}},
                  {taskID: 8, "title": "something8", subtasks: {}}];
                  
const sortingArray = [8, 1, 5];

const result = sortingArray.flatMap(so=>toSortArray.filter(ts=>ts.taskID === so));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use map and find as:

```js
toSortArray = [{ taskID: 1, "title": "something1", subtasks: {} },
    { taskID: 5, "title": "something5", subtasks: {} },
    { taskID: 8, "title": "something8", subtasks: {} }];
    
sortingArray = [8, 1, 5];
    
const result = sortingArray.map((item) => toSortArray.find((element) => element.taskID === item));
    
console.log(result);
```